# mix-blend-mode not working in webkit-browsers when element is direct child of body

Tags: html, css, webkit, mix-blend-mode

I can't get an svg image with `fill="#fff"` to show on a white background using `mix-blend-mode: difference` in webkit browsers like chrome or edge.

It is working fine in firefox. Check out this Fiddle for reference: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Florian_W7/d6Lzwa25/9/)

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.volume-icon {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <img class="volume-icon" src='https://svgshare.com/i/HxZ.svg'>
</body>
```

Comment: `mix-blend-mode` doesn't work in Edge: https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode

Comment: but shouldn't it work in chrome?

Comment: Yes, it should, but you wont make it work in Edge, so another solution would be preferred, if you want it to work in all browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are facing an issue related to background propogation since background applied to `body` has [a special behavior](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#body-background)

If you consider another container it will work fine:

```css
div {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.volume-icon {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="volume-icon" src='https://svgshare.com/i/HxZ.svg'>
</div>
```

With the `body` element you need to provide a background to `html` different from transparent and it will work:

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.volume-icon {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}


html {
  background-color: #fff; /* even the same color will do the job */
}
```

```html
<img class="volume-icon" src='https://svgshare.com/i/HxZ.svg'>
```