# Animate icon sequence and reverse direction in infinite loop

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate icons to show this infinite sequence:

```
1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 ...
```

So `1 2 3`, then reverse direction back to `1`, then reverse up to `3`, etc.

This is what I managed to do:

```css
.fader .icon {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  /*animation-direction: alternate;*/
}

@keyframes fade {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
   33% { opacity: 0; }
   66% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

#icon3 { animation-delay:  0s; }
#icon2 { animation-delay: -1s; }
#icon1 { animation-delay: -2s; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css"  />

<div class="fader mt-3 ms-3">
  <div class="position-relative">
    <span id="icon3" class="icon bi bi-3-square fs-1 position-absolute top-0 start-0"></span>
    <span id="icon2" class="icon bi bi-2-square fs-1 position-absolute top-0 start-0"></span>
    <span id="icon1" class="icon bi bi-1-square fs-1 position-absolute top-0 start-0"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently it goes one way only, without "reversing" direction. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: the `animation-direction` drives the animation of each span alone (1,2,3) and not the animation in terms of their sequence. That's why you are having an inconsistent opacity change over time. The sequence instead is driven by the `animation-delay` and that "parameter" doesn't change over time. The question is: are you looking for a css solution only or is js allowed?

Comment: @DiegoD css only is what I'm after. I toyed with the `animation-direction` and didn't manage to get it to work either way. I commented it out above.

Comment: I think this post might give you some hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60957638/forward-and-reverse-animating-multiple-divs-in-sequence-using-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We set it in shorthand using 'alternate' 1-2-3-2-1-infinite.
In longhand it is:

```
animation-name: fade;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

```css
.icon {
  position-relative;
  animation: fade 4s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes fade {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
   25% { opacity: 0; }
   50% { opacity: 0; }
   75% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

#icon1 { animation-delay:  0s; }
#icon2 { animation-delay: -1s; }
#icon3 { animation-delay: -2s; }
#icon4 { animation-delay: -3s; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="fader mt-3 ms-3">
  <div>
    <span id="icon1" class="icon bi bi-1-square fs-1 position-absolute top-0 start-0"></span>
    <span id="icon2" class="icon bi bi-2-square fs-1 position-absolute top-0 start-0"></span>
    <span id="icon3" class="icon bi bi-3-square fs-1 position-absolute top-0 start-0"></span>
    <span id="icon4" class="icon bi bi-2-square fs-1 position-absolute top-0 start-0"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```